# Categories don't work after migration, shows "Class do not exits"'

Tags: magento2.3, category, delta-migration

I am running Magneto 2.3.4 version I migrate the database successfully, but my false I don't check categories after migration and I start working. 
So now I have an error that I can't resolve "Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class does not exist ". The problem is that the Class is empty.

I am sending you a screenshot from error.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: all remove var/cache and run all command after ...

Comment: I already have running all commands, cleared cache, generate code again ... but nothing